# Process Creation Using Fork()

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, system-calls

On running the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
static int x = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t p = getpid();
    fork();
    x++;

    if (! fork()) {
      x++;
      if (fork()) {
          x++;
      }
    }

    printf("p%d: x = %d\n", getpid() - p, x);
    sleep(60);
     return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
p0: x = 1
p1: x = 1
p2: x = 3
p3: x = 3
p4: x = 2
p5: x = 2
```

I don't quite understand how and where the values are incremented. The **original process (p0)** executes the main() function. The first fork() creates a
**child process (p1)**. Both, p0 and p1 then set their copy of x to 1.

Next, both processes create another child process **(p2 and p3) on the second fork**. The two new child processes p2
and p3 increment their copy of x, i.e., their copy of **x becomes 2**. But **what about p0 and p1**? Do they not increment the values?

What's next? How are the values incremented for **p4 and p5**? Could someone please explain step wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fork` returns one of the following:

- `-1` on error (and sets `errno`).
- `0` in the child.
- The child's pid (a true value) in the parent.

Assuming `fork` doesn't fail, this means `!fork()` is only true in the child, and `fork()` is only true in the parent.

```
                                       p0 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
                                       -- -- -- -- -- --
static int x = 0;                   x = 0

// p1 created as a copy of p0.
fork();                                 0  0

x++;                                    1  1

// p2 created as a copy of p0.
// p3 created as a copy of p1.
if (! fork()) {                         1  1  1  1
  // Only p2 and p3 reach here.
  x++;                                  1  1  2  2

  // p4 created as a copy of p2.
  // p5 created as a copy of p3
  if (fork()) {                         1  1  2  2  2  2
      // Only p2 and p3 reach here.
      x++;                              1  1  3  3  2  2
  }
}
```

Comment: this answer would be more helpful if you used the same numbering scheme as the OP (p0...p5)

Comment: @x89 this is more than just a good answer.  it shows a technique, a way of thinking/reasoning about the problem that can help you in the future.  this is basically what i did (on paper) when i saw your question, but ikegami presents an even better visual representation here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key to your misunderstanding relies in the return value of the fork syscall.
When calling fork, it returns different values for the newly-created process (aka child) and the old process (aka parent).

In the child process, fork returns 0.

In the parent process, fork returns the PID of the child process.

When writing `if (fork())` for example, the parent process will enter the if clause, but the child will not. It works the other way as well - when writing `if (!fork())`, the child process will enter the if clause, but he parent will not.